# how to create unique id for each input fields using java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used `for` loop for copying the table to n times. For loop works only on first loop . I know it doesn't works until i use unique id for each. But ,i don't know how to create a unique id. I am a beginner. Please help me.

This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3shjhu98/3/

Comment: Try appending i value of for loop to it,

clone.id = "newID" + i;

Comment: `clone.id = "newID"+i;` will work

Comment: Wait a min bro i ll try and come back.

Comment: @Gokulan P H and @ atulquest93 will you please update my fidddle with your suggested changes.I ll learn from it.

Comment: why you adding space in ID attribute? please read a basic guidelines of html.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to generate unique IDs in other for loops, a generator helper function would be best.

```
var id = 0;
function uniqueID(prefix){
   return prefix + "_" + id++;
}

cloned_table.id = uniqueID("table");
```

**added jsfiddle link**
https://jsfiddle.net/3shjhu98/8/

Comment: Please update this change in my fiddle.I ll learn from it buddy.I dnt know whr to change.